# Webview InputText not supported in 2.1 and 2.2

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In Android we have an url

```
"http://offers.bartizan.com/we-want-ileads-at-our-shows"
```

which contains lot of data.

We load this url in webview, In android 2.3 and onwards its working fine means diplay all content of url data but in android 2.1 and 2.2 not display Input Text form.

Here is my code which i used to load url in webview.

```
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
     webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
     webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
     webView.enablePlatformNotifications();
     webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

webView.loadUrl("http://offers.bartizan.com/we-want-ileads-at-our-shows");

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 //if(url.contains("http://www.youtube.com/embed/")){
                      Log.d("WBC", "This is a YouTube link: " + url);
                      Log.e("url---Video->", url);
                      view.loadUrl(url);
                       return true;
             }  });
       class MyJavaScriptInterface {
         public void showHTML(String html) {
             String htmlString = html;
               Log.e("<---MyJavaScriptInterface---showHTML----->", htmlString);
       }
     }
```

Below form not display in android OS. 2.1 and 2.2

First name *

Last name

Email address *

List the names of your shows here. Please include the show manager name, email and phone. *

1) Showing blank area above image

[image]

2) Textbox we require

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error meesage in logcat for 2.1 and 2.2 os?

Comment: @SiddharthVyas : No i am not getting any LogCat...